# SSIS Data QC methods

Tags: sql, ssis

I get a set of monthly data every month, mostly with the same columns. I'm loading these files manually using Import/Export wizard. Usually, I load this data with a date stamp, so that I can compare old data that was provided last month to the new data. I keep the new data if the variance is less than 5%, otherwise, I have to go back to the vendor and ask for an explanation for the difference.

I'm trying to automate this in SSIS but not sure how to do the QC part. Any suggestions?

Comment: please include examples of what you've tried along with what worked (and what didn't). good tips here: [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

My recommended workflow in one single SSIS package.

1. Truncate the staging table `SQL Task`.
2. Load the incoming monthly file into the staging table. If there is a layout issue the package fails `DFT`.
3. Compare the staging table against the records of the last-monthly load `SQL Task, Expression Task`. If the variance is above the threshold, email to the vendor `Send Email Task`. The other option of notification, which I prefer, is to insert a record into an error logging table and then use SSRS to send out the error notification. Generally, I prefer not doing non-sql tasks in SSIS.
4. Insert the Staging table records into the final table `DFT` and insert a record into the import log table `SQL Task`.